# Atributo download en HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```html
<a href="download/test10.png" download="Press">Download Text</a>
```

Al hacer la prueba en IE no realiza la descarga

Comment: Internet Explorer no soporta ese atributo https://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score -3):

Es posible que no encuentre el documento que quiere descargar.

Modifica tu etiqueta a y añádele `../` Para que busque con una ruta dinámica.

Te dejo un ejemplo con tu mismo código.

```html
<a href="../download/test10.png" download="Press">Download Text</a>
```

Espero sea de utilidad.